# Classification of groups without proper subgrouups

Tags: group-theory

I saw the following question from the book by Gallian on abstract algebra.

If G is a group such that it has no proper subgroup then I need to show that order of G is prime. In brackets, he mentions that I'm not to assume that the order is finite.

My question is : Isn't it obvious that if I have to show that the cardinality is prime, then it is finite. In fact, I don't get how one shows that the order is prime without assuming that it is finite.

The proof after assuming that the order is a natural number is trivial, follows from Lagrange's theorem.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks :)

Comment: He means you first have to separately prove that the order is finite, then once you know that, prove that it's prime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean a group $G$ with identity $1$ and with more than one member and no proper subgroup except the one-element subgroup $\{1\}$.Take $x\in G$ with $x\ne 1$. Let $H=\{x^n : n \in Z\}$.Since $H$ is a subgroup of $G$ and $H\ne \{1\}$,we have $H=G$.Now if $x^m\ne x^n$ whenever  $m,n$ are distinct integers then $\{x^{2n}: n\in Z\}$ is a proper subgroup of G not equal to $\{1\}$, which can't be, so it must be that $x^m=x^n$ for some distinct $m,n$, which gives $x^{|m-n|}=1$. So $G$ is finite and cyclic,and as you said,the rest is easy.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that any non-trivial element $x$ generates the whole group i.e. the group is cyclic. Then take an integer $r\gt 1$. If $x^r$ is not the identity there is an integer $k$ with $x^{rk}=x$.

Answer (score 0):

As you said, once you know that any such group has to be finite, the conclusion is almost straightforward applying Lagrange's theorem.

The point of saying that we don't need to assume that the order of the group is finite is then obvious. Because of what we said above $G$ finite without proper subgroups implies $G$ of prime order is an easy exercise, whereas $G$ without proper subgroups implies $G$ is finite and of prime order is a better implication (much stronger) and of course not so hard.

Now for a proof of that $G$ without proper subgroups needs to be finite. Take $G$ such a group and $g\in G$ with $g$ not trivial. Then the subgroup generated by $g$ cannot be trivial, by assumption it cannot be proper, hence $G$ is generated by $g$.

If $G$ happens to be infinite then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ by sending $g$ to $1$. Now $2\mathbb{Z}< \mathbb{Z}$ is a proper subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ so this contradicts the assumption on $G$. Whence $G$ is finite and hence cyclic by what we wrote before. At this point you will be able to conclude.

Comment: Very explicit. Thanks a lot. :)